# Rearrange longitudinal data set to life table

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-wrangling

I have a table on residency and occupation for a number of individuals. I want to find out if individuals with certain occupations are more likely of relocating than others. The longitudinal data looks like this:

```
library(tidyverse)    
id <- c(rep(1, 6), rep(2, 6), rep(3, 6))
year <- c(rep(1990:1995, 3))
occupation <- c(rep("Barrister", 6), rep("Telephone salesman", 3), rep("Baker", 3), rep("Janitor", 2), rep("Builder", 4))
residence <- c(rep("London", 2), rep("Manchester", 2), rep("Glasgow", 2), rep("London", 6), rep("Liverpool", 4), rep ("Luton", 2))

df <- tibble(id, year, occupation, residence)
```

I want to rearrange the table so that it takes a life table format. Additionally, I want to create two new variables: one dummy variable for whether the individual relocated after x number of years (= event happened) or if the individual did not relocate after x number of years (= event was right-censored), and one variable containing information on previously held occupation if an individual changed occupation. I want the table to look like this:

```
id2 <- c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 2), rep(3, 3))         
years <- c(2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2)
occupation2 <- c(rep("Barrister", 3), rep("Telephone salesman", 1), rep("Baker", 1), rep("Janitor", 1), rep("Builder", 2))
residence2 <- c(rep("London", 1), rep("Manchester", 1), rep("Glasgow", 1), rep("London", 2), rep("Liverpool", 2), rep ("Luton", 1))
relocated <- c(1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0)
experience <- c(rep(NA, 3), rep(NA, 1), rep("Telephone salesman", 1), rep(NA, 1), rep("Janitor", 2))

life.table <- tibble(id2, years, occupation2, residence2, relocated, experience)
```

I'm not sure at all how to achieve this and any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is the expected output correct.  It is not clear about the values in `relocated` column

Comment: Well the idea is to have the relocated = 1 if the individual was living in a new location in the next observation. Did you see any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be, this helps

```
library(dplyr)
n <- 2
df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(n1 = cumsum(c(1, diff(year))), n2 = n(), n3 = n2 - n1, 
         n4 = n_distinct(residence)) %>% 
    group_by(occupation = factor(occupation, levels = unique(occupation)), 
       residence = factor(residence, levels = unique(residence)), .add = TRUE) %>%
    summarise(years = n(), relocated = +(any(n3 > n) & first(n4) > 1)) %>%
    group_by(id) %>% 
    mutate(experience = if(n_distinct(occupation) > 1)
     c(NA_character_, rep(as.character(first(occupation)), n() - 1))
     else NA_character_)
```

Comment: Did you get the "Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `relocated`.
x comparison (6) is possible only for atomic and list types" error when you ran the code?

Comment: @johnny I didn't get any error.  is it based on the same example or different.  What is your `packageVersion('dplyr')`

Comment: The same example as the one I posted. I have version ‘1.0.2’.

Comment: I recreated the objects and the data frame as I had done in the top code chunk. Then I ran your code, but then I got the error message.

Comment: @johnny Sorry, I forgot to add the `n <- 2` as threshold.  Can you try now